# Chrome webcam access issue

Tags: google-chrome, drivers, browser, webcam

Whenever I try to access my webcam in chrome. Every time, it turns on for 2 seconds and then turn off automatically.

I tried all different solutions like clearing caches and cookies, toggling webcam permissions, reinstalling chrome, reinstalling webcam, updating webcam drivers but nothing worked.

At last, I tried to drop the browser version and boom I found out **webcam was working fine in chrome v60 and below**.

When I check on [webcamtests.com/](https://webcamtests.com/) website it given me the following error:
[error-screenshot-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BdZoi.png)
[error-screenshot-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zl2eg.png)